# System.Net.Http.HttpClient Timeout seems to be ignored

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am using Xamarin.iOS Version: 8.10.5.26 (Indie Edition) and facing a very strange behaviour with timing out requests sent with HttpClient():

The following code tries to get a result from an url, and has 60 seconds timeout (1 minutes), but when the request is fired it is taking around 90 seconds for time out. When call is made, I manually turn off the network connectivity to check the time out. It is observed that it is taking more than 60 seconds.

**CODE**

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string,object>> GetPatientDataASync (string lUsername)
    {
        var lDict = new Dictionary<string,object> ();
        try {
            string lQuerystring = "{Email: '" + lUsername + "'}";
            String lUrl = String.Format (Constants.mURLPatient + "?where={0}", JObject.Parse (lQuerystring));
            var lClient = new HttpClient ();
            lClient.BaseAddress = new Uri (lUrl);
            lClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/json"));
            lClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", Constants.mKeyParseAppId);
            lClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Constants.mKeyRestAPIKey);
            lClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan (0, 1, 0);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage ();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            if (Utility.isNetworkConnected ()) {
                bool responseStatus = false;
                await lClient.SendAsync (request)
                    .ContinueWith (responseTask => {
                    if (responseTask != null) {
                        var response = responseTask.Result;
                        if (response != null) {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                                var responseContent = response.Content;
                                if (responseContent != null) {
                                    string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (responseString)) {
                                        JObject json = JObject.Parse (responseString);
                                        if (json != null) {
                                            if (json ["results"].Any ()) {
                                                Patient user = Patient.Instance;
                                                user.objectId = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].objectId").Value<string> ();
                                                user.Email = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].Email").Value<string> ();
                                                user.Name = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].Name").Value<string> ();
                                                user.IsNotificationsEnabled = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].IsNotificationsEnabled").Value<string> ();

                                                Application.Current.Properties ["IsNotificationsEnabled"] = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].IsNotificationsEnabled").Value<string> ();

                                                if (json.SelectToken (@"results[0].DeviceToken") != null) {
                                                    var deviceToken = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].DeviceToken").Value<JArray> ();
                                                    if (deviceToken != null)
                                                        user.DeviceToken = deviceToken.ToObject < List<string>> ();
                                                } else {
                                                    user.DeviceToken = new List<string> ();
                                                }

                                                var doctors = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].MyDoctors").Value<JArray> ();
                                                user.AllergicTo = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].AllergicTo").Value<string> ();
                                                user.ContactNo = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].ContactNo").Value<string> ();
                                                user.BloodGroup = json.SelectToken (@"results[0].BloodGroup").Value<string> ();
                                                user.MyDoctors = doctors != null ? doctors.ToObject<List<string>> () : new List<string> ();
                                                responseStatus = true;
                                            } else
                                                responseStatus = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
              lDict.Add (SUCCESS_CODE, responseStatus);
                return lDict;
            } else {
                lDict.Add (NO_INTERNET, Constants.mStringNoInternetMessage);
                return lDict;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine (e.Message + "\n " + e.StackTrace);
            lDict.Add (EXCEPTION_OCCURED, e);
            return lDict;
        }
    }
```

If there's some mistake in my code , please do let me know.
Also the same issues are reported here :-

1. [First link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5941/system-net-http-httpclient-timeout-seems-to-be-ignored)
2. [Second Link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13200)

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug which was opened, closed and re-opened several times over the years. It is already reported [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13200) and [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24704).

Answer (score 0):

There is work-around solution:

1. Define `CancellationTokenSource` and Set `Token` to http request;
2. Invoke cancel by timeout on `CancellationTokenSource` like this `cts.CancelAfter(timeout);`:
3. Don't forgot catch exception, like this.

---

```
try
{
}
catch(TaskCanceledException)
{
    if(!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {// timeout
    }
    else
    {//other reason
    }
}
```